# Calculus: Integration problem.

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

Does there exist a function $f(x) \neq \dfrac{1}{x}$  such that $\int_1^{\infty} f(x) \mathrm d{x} = \log t$ for all $t>0$ ?

Note: the exception $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$ was treated as the limit of $\int_1^{t} f(x) \mathrm d{x}$ as $t$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Do you mean: for a particular $t > 0$, does there exist a function $f$ which is not the function $x \mapsto 1/x$ such that

$$\int_1^\infty f(x) \ dx = \log t$$

Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean:

> for a particular $t > 0$, does there exist a function $f$ which is not the function $x \mapsto 1/x$ such that
>
> $$\int_1^\infty f(x) \ dx = \log t$$

then the answer is yes. For instance

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \log t, & 1 \leq x \leq 2 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

*added (see comment below) an example of a continuous function*

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \left(1 - \frac{x-1}2 \right)\log t, & 1 \leq x \leq 3 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

*example of $C^\omega$ function*
$$f(x) = e^{-(x-1)}\cdot\log t$$

If instead you are asking:

> does there exist an $f$ which is not the function $x \mapsto 1/x$ such that $$\int_1^t f(x) \ dx = \log t$$ **for all** $t > 0$

then the answer is no. Apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and differentiate both sides.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Simon...but on the second part why do we now have the limits from $1$ to $t$ instead from $1$ to $\infty$ ?

Comment: Or maybe you changed the limits of integration to $[1, t]$ and then took the limit of the *integral* as $t$ tends to infinity ?

Comment: I am trying to clarify your question (and giving answers to two possible versions). What exactly is it you are asking? Is it either of the versions I have given, or something else?

Comment: the second version you gave is what i'm asking...

Comment: Then let me know if the answer is not clear. I'll just add that

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \int_1^t \frac{dx}{x} = \lim_{t\to\infty} \log t$$
in the sense that both limits diverge to positive $\infty$

Comment: Exactly, it's now clear. Thank you.

Comment: Good. Custom on this site is to upvote and/or accept an answer that addresses your question.

Comment: I think i just accepted your answer (as shown by the green tick). It seems however that i can't upvote due to my presently incomplete registration details...

Comment: Curiously, for the first version of the question, is there any example where $f(x)$ is not a piecewise function ?

Comment: Yes, see edits above

Answer (score 0):

This is just a minor modification of Simon's answer:

Suppose $\int_1^{\infty} f(x) \mathrm {d}x = \log t$ for all $t > 0$

This be written in the form $\lim_ {t \to \infty} \int_1^{t} f(x) \mathrm {d}x = \log t$

From here we can then apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and differentiate both sides and conclude that the only possibility is $f(x) = x^{-1}$.